# What's a normal word count for a children's novel or collection?

Tags: wordcount, children

How many words are normal for a children's novel?

Say 5th - 8th grade, if that's the best way to measure it.

Comment: If someone can point us to some sort of guideline for children's books in general, that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: At Amazon the page count for books for 10-years-old children varies from 120 to 350. Pick up a children's book in your collection and count the words on one page. Multiply it with the page count and you get a vague idea.

Comment: Don't they put kid's books in bigger font too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Colleen Lindsay (former agent), a middle grade novel has on average 35K words.

http://theswivet.blogspot.com/2008/03/on-word-counts-and-novel-length.html

Answer (score 1):

If you write a ***really*** good story like Harry Potter, you can get away with making kids read an almost infinite amount of words.  Although, you'll notice with the Harry Potter books the length of each book increases with each release in the series. So if you're writing a series, start small, then increase the word count with each release.

Publishers are probably more open to this approach, since when you become more established, there's less risk for them with bigger books.

Comment: I don't believe Harry Potter was classified as a Children's Novel. I believe it was classified as Young Adult, which is totally different. Children's and Middle Grade novels are going to be much shorter and, for the most part, more simplistic.

Comment: I don't believe Harry Potter was classified as a ***really*** good story.

Comment: no Harry Potter is a childrens book, not young adult.

Comment: Fantasy books are always thicker and are not the best reference, unless for other fantasy works. Since the first book was meant for children around 13 years of age, I do believe that qualifies as a Children's novel. Since the readership grew together with Harry, the last book or two <i>might</i> pass as young adult, even though it doesn't have all the elements that make it YA - an MC that's in late teens does not automatically mean YA. @Vic Goldfeld - for a not really good story, it sure made the author the richest writer ever.

Comment: Harry Potter starts as a children's or middle grade book and then changes: the target age rises. 'The Prisoner of Azkaban' definitely isn't aimed at the same age and the first one.